# Importing module returns null using expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, import, expo

I'm trying to import a compass module without success using expo and react native

[LINK to library](https://github.com/vnil/react-native-simple-compass)

The error appears when I uncomment the import line, which gives me the error:

```
import RNSimpleCompass from 'react-native-simple-compass';

null is not an Object (Evaluating 'RNSimpleCompass.start')
```

I basically install the library using the provided instructions:

```
npm install react-native-simple-compass --save
```

I also tried linking it

```
npx react-native link react-native-simple-compass
```

then I run

```
npm start
```

which starts expo and gives me the error

I usually install and run other npm packages without problem, but this one keeps complaining when importing it.

I checked that the library is in my package.json dependencies. I even tried deleting the node_modules folder and re running npm install to reinstall all dependencies, but the error persist.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

When you have expo "managed" project (without "ios" and "android" directories) you can't use react-native libraries that contain native code(objc or java). It worked in other cases because you probably were adding js only libraries or libraries that are explicitly supported by expo.

If you want to use that library you would need to eject to bare workflow(`expo eject`). You will still have access to all expo libraries you are currently using, but you won't be able to build it on Expo servers.